# Building the DropThings ASP.NET Solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm attempting to build a project called DropThings but I am getting all these errors and I'm not sure how to resolve them.  Can anyone lend a helping hand?  I'm wondering if anyone else can build the website and if so, what steps it took you.  Thanks in advance!

**Source Code:**  http://code.google.com/p/dropthings/

**My Configuration:**

Visual Studio 2008 SP1
SQL 2005 (with the database loaded + Web.Config file configured)
Microsoft Silverlight Projects 2008

**Errors:**

Error   File
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\bin\Debug\Dropthings.DataAccess.dll' could not be found.
   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardBusiness
Build failed due to validation errors in ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\DropthingsDataContext.dbml.  Open the file and resolve the issues in the Error List, then try rebuilding the project.
    ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\DropthingsDataContext.dbml
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardBusiness\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.dll' could not be found.
   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Activities
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\bin\Debug\Dropthings.DataAccess.dll' could not be found.
   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Activities
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Activities\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.Activities.dll' could not be found.
   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Workflows
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardBusiness\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.dll' could not be found.
   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Workflows
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\bin\Debug\Dropthings.DataAccess.dll' could not be found.   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Workflows
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\bin\Debug\Dropthings.DataAccess.dll' could not be found    Dropthings.Widget.Framework
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardBusiness\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.dll' could not be found.   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Facade
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\bin\Debug\Dropthings.DataAccess.dll' could not be found.   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Facade
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\bin\Debug\Dropthings.DataAccess.dll' could not be found    Dropthings.Web.Framework
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Workflows\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.Workflows.dll' could not be found  Dropthings.Web.Framework
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Activities\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.Activities.dll' could not be found    Dropthings.Web.Framework
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Widget.Framework\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Widget.Framework.dll' could not be found  Dropthings.Web.Framework
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings.Business.Facade\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.Facade.dll' could not be found    Dropthings.Web.Framework
Metadata file '...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardBusiness\bin\Debug\Dropthings.Business.dll' could not be found    Dropthings.Web.Framework
The type or namespace name 'Framework' does not exist in the namespace 'Dropthings.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\Dropthings\web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could possibly be the hardcoded connection string in the dbml file:

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;F:\Ilias Vai\Dropthings\trunk\src\Dropthings\App_Data\dropthings.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

You're getting a build error on that:

> ..\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardBusiness Build failed due to validation errors in 
>   ...\Dropthings-v2.2.0\src\DashboardDataAccess\DropthingsDataContext.dbml. Open the file and resolve the issues in the Error List, then try rebuilding the project.

So you probably need to fix that connectionString to point your local MDF file (assuming you're using SQLEXPRESS) or a database.

Answer (score 1):

Check project's references.

Comment: Hum, I'm still having a problem building this solution.  I think I sorted out most of my issues, but now I get a runtime error in the web.config:

Comment: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Framework' does not exist in the namespace 'Dropthings.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

<profile enabled="true" automaticSaveEnabled="false" defaultProvider="DropthingsProfileSqlProvider" inherits="Dropthings.Web.Framework.UserProfile">

Comment: Are there all DropThings .dll files located in /bin folder of your project?

Comment: .dll files are not being build correctly.  That is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the .dll referenced by Dropthings are all present.

Take a look at the deploy version on GoogleCode which should work as-is.